# Is "bounded" and "Cauchy-continuous" function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Is a "bounded" and "Cauchy-continuous" function uniformly continuous?
I have found lots of questions that ask whether "bounded" and "continuous" function is uniformly continuous. (I know the answer is no, by the way. e.g. $\sin(\frac 1 x)$ at $(0,1)$).
However, if the image of a Cauchy sequence in $X$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, and also $X$ bounded, is the function uniformly continuous?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $X$ a subset of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: X is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ !

Comment: The function can be extended continuously to the closure of $X$, which is closed and bounded. Then f is uniformly continuous

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It really was helpful :)